# Matrix Rotation

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to follow wikipedia's page about matrix rotation and having a hard time understanding where the formula comes from.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix Wiki page about it.

what i have so far:

y<sub>2</sub>=sin(*a<sub>1</sub>+a<sub>2</sub>*)R  -> where R is hypotenuse, a1 is current angle and a2 is the angle by which something must rotate.

this how i used to calculate my rotation, but it takes long time to compute and uses up a lot of cpu time for square roots and other heavy stuff due tot he need of finding the initial angle.

So i decided to reduce computation time and found that sin(a1+a2) could be writen as `sin(a1)cos(a2)+cos(a1)sin(a2)` and from there i got to the point where it is:

y<sub>2</sub>=y<sub>1</sub>cos(*a<sub>2</sub>*)+xsin(*a<sub>2</sub>*)sin(*a<sub>1</sub>*)

But wiki page says that it must b:

y<sub>2</sub>=y<sub>1</sub>cos(*a<sub>2</sub>*)+xsin(*a<sub>2</sub>*)

[My work book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRzo7.png)

Comment: No need to go from cartesian to polar, add the angle and back to cartesian. Just work in cartesian coordinates with trigonometry,

Comment: @ja72 it is not polar cordinates, it is a circle i drew to come up with rotation in general. how it actually happens.

Comment: When you do $R=\sqrt{\ldots}$ and $\theta =\arctan\left( \ldots \right)$ you are doing polar coordinates.

Comment: @ja72 looks like i need to learn a lot more:) but your answer actually helped a lot at understanding :)

Comment: If it really helped you then please vote up.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a rotated rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$

[image: sketch]

Do the trigonometry to find the *x* and *y* coordinates of point **P**.

The red triangle contributes $a \cos \theta$ horizontally, and $a \sin \theta$ vertically. The blue triangle contributes $-b \sin\theta$ horizontally, and $b\cos \theta$ vertically.

Add them up for

$$ \pmatrix{Px \\ Py} = \pmatrix{ a \cos \theta - b \sin \theta \\ a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta} $$

Now factor the rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$

$$ \pmatrix{Px \\ Py} = \pmatrix{\cos\theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta} \pmatrix{a \\ b} $$

The vector $\pmatrix{Px & Py}$ is the rotated vector $\pmatrix{a & b}$ by an angle $\theta$ and from geometry you derive the rotation matrix.

Comment: Ohhhh :) now i get it. Could u please take a look at the image i added tot he post and tell where i took the wrong turn. i am new to trigonometry and had to reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 0):

Think: where are the unit vectors $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ sent to under a rotation by angle $\theta$? It should not take too long to convince yourself that the answers are $(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$ and $(-\sin \theta, \cos\theta)$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You've not shown how you got a different result, so I can't comment on your mistake. But it looks to me like you're examining the composition of rotations about the origin in $2$ dimensions. (@bounceback gave an answer that understood your aims differently, so I hope between us we give you the help you need.) Let's denote one rotation as $R(\theta):=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{array}\right)$. Then$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos a_2 & -\sin a_2\\ \sin a_2 & \cos a_2 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos a_1 & -\sin a_1\\ \sin a_1 & \cos a_1 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos a_{1}\cos a_2-\sin a_1\sin a_2 & -\sin a_1\cos a_2-\sin a_2\cos a_1\\ \sin a_1\cos a_2+\sin a_2\cos a_1 & \cos a_1\cos a_2-\sin a_1\sin a_2 \end{array}\right)$$is an exercise in matrix multiplication, and the right-hand side reduces by trigonometric identities to$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos(a_1+a_2) & -\sin (a_1+a_2)\\\sin(a_1+a_2) & \cos(a_1+a_2)\end{array}\right).$$In other words, $R(a_2)R(a_1)=R(a_1+a_2)$, and if we rotate a vector $v$ to $R(a_1)v$ and then to $R(a_2)R(a_1)v$ the final result is $R(a_1+a_2)v$. (If you write all this in terms of $x$- and $y$-coordinates, you can remove a discussion of vectors and matrices altogether.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! yeah same stuff is on wiki page as well, just wanted to add that i started learning algebra in general about 3 days ago. and sometimes it is hard for me to understand this notations.

But, the question is, how did you come up with  R(0) rotation in first place.

Comment: @AntonStafeyev Do you mean why is the formula for $R(\theta)$ what it is in the first place? If so, bounceback's answer addresses that. (Drawing a diagram of the vectors might help.)

Comment: i added a picture so u can better understand what i am doing., it is a bit messy sorry for that